# How do i add a widget that will only appear on WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, sidebar

I want to add a widget that will only appear on the shop page, but I couldn't get any results.

`functions.php`

```
function kucuksun_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'kucuksun' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'kucuksun' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        ),
        register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Shop', 'kucuksun' ),
            'id'            => 'shop',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'kucuksun' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
       )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'kucuksun_widgets_init' );
```

Following my code: `sidebar.php`

```
<?php

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside>
```

I'm not exactly sure but I need to print it in
`woocommerce.php` `dynamic_sidebar( 'shop' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a sidebar with widgets that will only appear on the shop page,
you can apply the following simple steps:

1. Create a new php file, name it `sidebar-shop.php` and place it in your themes root folder
2. Copy/paste the code from `sidebar.php` to `sidebar-shop.php`
3. Place a widget in the sidebar, and it should only be visible on the shop page

---

Explanation: `page-{slug}.php` — If no custom template has been assigned, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized template that contains the page’s slug.